# Show one div and hide another in an array with onMouseEnter in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onmouseover

I have an array of items that i want to show with a map function, and every item is shown as a card.
I'm trying to show two kinds of cards with a different content, one if "isHover" is false, and the other if it true using onMouseEnter/onMouseOver.
I made "isHover" as an array in order to know which item to show/hide.
(The "isHover" array has the same length that the items' array has).
The problem is that when I hover one card it dissappears and nothing is shown in place of it. :(

The code:

```
function TeachersShow(props) {

const [isHover, setIsHover] = useState(null);

const updateIsHover = (index, isHover1) => {
 let newArray = isHover;
 newArray[index] = isHover1;
 setIsHover([...newArray]);
 console.log(isHover[index]);
};

return (
 <div>

         {isHover[index] === false && (<Card className="teacher-card"
         onMouseEnter={() => { updateIsHover(index, true) }}
         key={index}
         item={item}
         onClick={() => navigateToTeacher(item)}
       >
         <Card.Img className="teachersImg" src={item.photoURL}>
         </Card.Img>
         <Card.Title className=" teachersName">
           {item.username}
         </Card.Title>
       </Card>)}

       {isHover[index] === true  && (
         <Card className="card-hover"
         onMouseleave={() => { updateIsHover(index, false) }}
         key={index}
         item={item}
         onClick={() => navigateToTeacher(item)}
       >
     
         <Card.Title className=" teachersName">
           {item.username}
         </Card.Title>
         <Card.Subtitle className="proTeacher">
           {`${item.profession} teacher`}
         </Card.Subtitle>
         <Card.Text className="teacherDesc">
           {item.teacher_description}
         </Card.Text>
         </Card>)}
       

       </Col>
     ))}
     <Col></Col>
   </Row>

 </div>

);
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TeachersShow);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's little hard to tell what's wrong, since a lot of information is missing from the code. But try to create a component Let's say `<Teacher />`, and let it be responsible for hovering action. Try this:

```
function Teacher(item) {
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);

  const renderCardData = () => {
    if (!hover) {
      return (
        <Card.Img className="teachersImg" src={item.photoURL} />
        <Card.Title className="teachersName">
          {item.username}
        </Card.Title>
      );
    }

    return (
      <Card.Title className=" teachersName">
        { item.username }
      </Card.Title>
      <Card.Subtitle className="proTeacher">
        { `${item.profession} teacher` }
      </Card.Subtitle>
      <Card.Text className="teacherDesc">
        { item.teacher_description }
      </Card.Text>
    );
  };

  return (
    <Card
      className={ hover
        ? 'card-hover'
        : 'teacher-card' }
      onMouseEnter={ () => setHover(true) }
      onMouseLeave={ () => setHover(false) }
    >
      { renderCardData() }
    </Card>
  );
}

export default Teacher;
```

And you render it like that:

```
function TeachersList(teachers) {
  return teachers.map(Teacher);
};
```